# WSO2 API Manager: need to create API from backend using swagger file

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a requirement where I need to create APIs in wso2 api manager using swagger file for an API. Also, this should be created from backend.

I have been able to create APIs from backend as per the link https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/apidocs/publisher/#!/operations#APICollection#apisPost

but it does not take swagger file for an API. How can I create an API using swagger file from backend.

Please help as I am stuck here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to do this from publisher portal or publisher REST API?

Comment: I wanted to do this from publisher REST API

Comment: I do not understand. Why not create a new 'api_create' request, put your swagger file in the apiDefinition field and have your backend fill out the other details?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. You will have to follow the payload definition which is defined in the Post request.

Even if you try to import a Swagger file in API Manager publisher, still you need to manually change the API name, throttling policies and etc when creating the API.

Comment: So in the API definition, is it allowed to include the Models also for the APIs.
As I was checking in the sample, only URI path, responses are mentioned. So can we include more fields into the definition or it has to be as it is.